# Is there a maximum storage space configuration in HDFS or HBase?

Tags: hadoop, configuration, hdfs, hbase

Is there a maximum storage space configuration in HDFS or HBase?

I've found

- **dfs.data.dir**:    "*Comma separated list of paths on the local filesystem of a DataNode where it should store its blocks*" and
- **dfs.datanode.du.reserved**: but it's for non DFS space reserved for HDFS

in the [hadoop documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/cluster_setup.html#Configuration+Files)

For HBase I've found some heap size configurations and compaction intervals, Memstore Flush Size, but none of these seem to regulate maximum size for a single node.

**Is there any configuration for either HBase or HDFS that regulates how much space they will occupy in a single node?**

(I am running tests on a single machine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, `dfs.data.dir` will be a formatted volume that is mounted *specifically* for HDFS data. Therefore, the "maximum" is the number of physical SATA/USB/M.2 NVME connectors on the datanode's motherboard times the size of the largest hard-drives you can find.

If not using dedicated volumes/devices, the max is still limited by the disk sizes, but `dfs.datanode.du.reserved` will leave space for the OS to run on its own.

Neither is related to memory usage / heap space

Comment: So I guess an approximation for the maximum size would be the number of physical SATA/USB/m2e connectors on the datanode's motherboard times the size of the largest hard-drives you can find minus the dfs.datanode.du.reserved property?

Comment: If you have an infinite budget, then that is your upper bound, yes